# How can I model bind to a textbox placeholder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, textbox, model-binding, placeholder

I have been able to bind the info to the textbox like so:

```
<div id="wordsInsideOfText">
        @foreach (var item in Model.KVpairs)
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item)
            <hr />
        }
</div>
```

but what I am trying to do is something like this:

```
<div id="wordsInsideOfText">
        @foreach (var item in Model.KVpairs)
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor().PlaceHolder(modelItem => item)
            <hr />
        }
    </div>
```

So that I can get the information from my model into the placeholder rather than as regular text.I have looked around some, and maybe I don't fully understand how to phrase my question/search but I wasn't able to come up with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item, new {placeholder = item})
```

or:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="@item"/>
```

Comment: I'd imagine the OP is using some third-party library that he neglected to mention. It looks similar in syntax to TwitterBootstrapMVC, but it's not that.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am not using any thirdparty software, but this is the answer I was looking for, thank you :)